# Swing: JList holding multiple Components as a single item

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist, imageicon

Here is my problem:
I'm creating a window that is responsible for listing a layer, where it displays the layer's
current image (in the form of a `ImageIcon` as of now), layer's name, and a check box to alter the current on/off state of said layer.  The entire thing is supposed to be a knock-off of [Paint.NET's Layer Window](http://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/LayersWindow.html), as seen here:

[image]

My problem has been how to bypass `JTable` to structure it as so.  I figure in the end I might have to resort to just making a dynamic table, but I am wondering if there is a way to make an item/container that can individually display those three components.

The closest I got was using a `JLabel` with its icon and text properties used, but I had trouble figuring out how to add the check box.

Should I use the layout manager to move the label list to the left, and add a new list filled with check boxes within the pane?

My code is probably as follows:

```
public class StudioLayerWindow extends JFrame
{
// Objects
JPanel buttonPanel;
JScrollPane layerScroll;

JButton addNewLayer;
JButton deleteCurrentLayer;
JButton duplicateCurrentLayer;
JButton mergeCurrentLayer;
JButton moveCurrentLayerUp;
JButton moveCurrentLayerDown;
JButton layerProperties;

// Constructors & Initializers
public StudioLayerWindow()
{
    // Main Window Initialization
    this.setTitle("Layers");
    this.setType(Type.UTILITY);
    this.setSize(200,200);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    initButtons();

    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,7));
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() /    7));
    buttonPanel.add(addNewLayer);
    buttonPanel.add(deleteCurrentLayer);
    buttonPanel.add(duplicateCurrentLayer);
    buttonPanel.add(mergeCurrentLayer);
    buttonPanel.add(moveCurrentLayerUp);
    buttonPanel.add(moveCurrentLayerDown);
    buttonPanel.add(layerProperties);

    // Code for what I'd add here
    layerScroll = new JScrollPane();

    this.add(layerScroll , BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(buttonPanel , BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}
```

The code above does not contain any of my tried solutions, only the basic template I have been at.

Is there any way to make multiple components on a single row?

Comment: *"My problem has been how to bypass `JTable` to structure it as so."*  Why 'bypass'?  A standard (3 column) `JTable` with vertical and horizontal lines suppressed could do that out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JList` is a generic class.

- Create a class which extends `JPanel`. (Let us call it `RowPanel`)
- Put all elements in it required to be present in a single row (using a horizontal layout)
- Create your `JList` using those panels like

  ```
  JList<RowPanel> list = new JList<RowPanel>();
  ```
- You can refer to this for creating `ListCellRenderer` and `ListCellEditor` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

---

**Note:** This should be done if you don't want to use `JTable` under any circumstances. `JTable` is a good alternative to this solution.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Is there a way to add `tool-tips` for each component in `JPanel`. I did this and I could add `tool-tips` only for the `JPanel`